# How bad is redefining/shadowing a local variable?

Tags: c++

While upgrading a legacy project to VS2015, I noticed there were a lot of errors where a local variable was redefined inside a function for example.

```
void fun()
{
    int count = applesCount();

    cout << "Apples cost= " << count * 1.25;

    for (int bag=0; bag<5;bag++)
    {
        int count = orangesCount(bag);

        cout << "Oranges cost = " << count * 0.75; 
    }
}
```

The error/warning message by compiler is:

```
declaration of 'count' hides previous local declaration
```

I know it is obviously not a good practice to use the same name for variable `count` but can the compiler really mess things up as well or generally they deal this situation rather gracefully?

Is it worth it to change and fix the variable names or is unlikely to cause any harm and is low or no risk?

Comment: Yes - for the simple reason - why make life harder than necessary

Comment: I guess its an error if you turn on warnings as error flag during build.

Comment: Anyway `count` is not a good name for a variable either

Comment: The question you should ask is, "How bad can it be?"

Comment: There should be no errors in your code, because shadowing is pretty valid.

Comment: The compiler should handle it fine; it's the humans reading the code that's the worrk here.  Reusing the same name in that way is a source of confusion.

Comment: The compiler doesn't care. It has a stack of scopes, armed and ready to find the nearest name.

Comment: Compiler is honey badger in this scenario.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I noticed there were a lot of errors where a local variable was redefined inside a function for example.

You are not demonstrating *redefining* here. You show an example of variable **shadowing**.

Variable shadowing is not an error syntactically. It is valid and well defined. However, if your intention was to use the variable from the outer scope, then you could consider it a logical error.

> but can the compiler really mess things up

No.

The problem with shadowing is that it can be hard to keep track of **for the programmer**. It is trivial for the compiler. You can find plenty of questions on this very site, stemming from confusion caused by shadowed variables.

It is not too difficult to grok which expression uses which variable in this small function, but imagine the function being dozens of lines and several nested and sequential blocks. If the function is long enough that you cannot see all the different definitions in different scopes at a glance, you are likely to make a misinterpretation.

> ```
> declaration of 'count' hides previous local declaration
> ```

This is a somewhat useful compiler *warning*. You haven't run out of names, so why not give a unique name for all local variables in the function? However, there is no need to treat this warning as an error. It is merely a suggestion to improve the readability of your program.

In this particular example, you don't need the `count` in the outer scope after the inner scope opens, so you might as well reuse one variable for both counts.

> Is it worth it to change and fix the variable names

Depends on whether you value more short term workload versus long term. Changing the code to use unique, descriptive local variable names is "extra" work now, but every time someone has to understand the program later, unnecessary shadowing will increase the mental challenge.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, bad coding practice.  Hard to maintain and read.

The compiler can discern between the outer variable and the internal variable.

With a good vocabulary (and a thesaurus), one doesn't need to use the same variable names.

Answer (score 4):

Shadowing a variable (which is what this is) has completely well defined semantics, so the *compiler* won't mess it up. It will do exactly what it has been told, with well defined result.

The problem is (as is often the case) with the humans. It is very easy to make mistakes when reading and modifying the code. If one is not very careful it can be tricky to keep track of which variable with a given name is being referenced and it's easy to make mistakes where you think you are modifying one but in reality you are modifying another.

So, the compiler is fine, the programmer is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, compilers usually handle this issue pretty gracefully.

However, it is **definitely** bad practice, and unless you have a really compelling reason to do so, you should either reuse the old variable (if it logically makes sense to do so), or declare a [differently-named] new variable.

Comment: Hopefully not just "usually". The behaviour is well defined, so a compiler that doesn't do the right thing is a buggy compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Can be very bad:

Consider this

```
std::vector<int> indices(100);
if (true) {
  std::vector<int> indices(100);
  std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);
}
// Now indices will be an all-0 vector instead of the an arithmetic progression!
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, compiling with Warning Level4 `/W4` will output a warning even when disambiguating by prefixing with the implicit `this` pointer, like in `this->Count`:

> warning C4458: declaration of 'Count' hides class member

Although the compiler rarely makes a mistake with the values, shadowing can be abused and get confusing overtime.

Below is an example of shadowing the Count member variable which should be avoided:

From the [Unreal Coding Standard](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/CodingStandard/) document.

```
class FSomeClass
{
public:
    void Func(const int32 Count)
    {
        for (int32 Count = 0; Count != 10; ++Count)
        {
            // Use Count
        }
    }

private:
    int32 Count;
}
```

One option to dealing with this would adding a prefix to the incoming argument name when shadowing occurs, like so:

```
class FSomeClass
{
public:
    void Func(const int32 InCount)
    {
        Count = InCount;
    
        for (int32 Counter = 0; Counter != 10; ++Counter)
        {
            // Use Count
        }
    }

private:
    int32 Count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using RAII resources it may actually simplify the code to shadow variables and not create new variable names.

An example, a simple logger which writes to stdout when entering and leaving a block:

```
class LogScope {
  private:
    std::string functionName;
    uint32_t lineNo;

  public:
    LogScope(std::string _functionName, uint32_t _lineNo) : 
      functionName(_functionName), lineNo(_lineNo) {
        std::cout << "Entering scope in " << functionName << " starting line " << lineNo << std::endl;
    };
    ~LogScope(void) {
        std:: cout << "Exiting scope in " << functionName << " starting line " << lineNo << std::endl;
    };
};
```

It could be used like:

```
void someFunction() { // First scope here.
    LogScope logScope(__FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    // some code...
    // A new block.
    // There is really no need to define a new name for LogScope.
    {
        LogScope logScope(__FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        // some code...
    }
```

}

Having said that, normally it is good practice, not to reuse your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Zar,

The compiler will handle this situation fine.  In your example, the count variable is defined in two different scopes '{}'.  Due to the scope of the variable, the assembly language will refer to two different addresses on the stack. The first 'count' might be the stack point, SP-8, while the inner count might be SP-4.  Once transformed into an address the name is irrelevant.

I would not generally change working code for stylistic reasons. If the code is a mess then you run the risk of breaking it.  Usually messy code doesn't have any good tests so it hard to know if you broke it.

If you need to enhance the code then certainly tidy up.

--Matt