# How to use the argument of a function in a loop which has a variable of the same name?

Tags: c++

I have a function which contains a loop. The loop has a variable of the same name as one of the function arguments/parameters.
Ex:-

```
void someFunction(int val, ...)
{
 ...
 for(int val = 0; val<10; val++)
 {
   cout<<val; //  <<----
 }
}
```

Whenever I use the variable "val" inside the loop, it is referenced to the variable of the loop, and not the function argument. How do I use the argument inside the loop?

Comment: Why don't you just rename one of them?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not, you are limited by the scope. Use a different name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533407/how-bad-is-redefining-shadowing-a-local-variable

Answer (score 1):

> How to use the argument of a function in a loop which has a variable of the same name?

You cannot.

Had `val` been a global variable or a variable in a `namespace`, you could explicitly use `::val` or `<TheNameSpace>::val` to disambiguate it from the loop variable. However, that cannot be used for arguments of the function or function local variables.

The more important question is: why do you want to do that? It's poor coding habit.

The name of the argument and the name of the variable used in the loop represent different things and should be named accordingly.

Comment: The reason why I want to do that because the code is given to me by someone else, and it was done this way in the original code. I wanted to know if there is some way to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @ronitvairagi, whoever gave you the code may have some reason for why they did it but it is poorly written code and you should feel free to change the names of the variables such that it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to std::cout the variable val passed as an argument to the function? If that's the case, you cannot do that if the argument-passed variable and for-loop-initialised variable are with the same name. In the scope of the for-loop you have intialised an integer with the value of 0, that happens to be with the same name as the argument passed (actually when you pass it that way (without a refference &) a copy is being made but that`s a different story). That means the argument-value is now equal to 0, the previous value is "lost" (the value of the copy by passing val).

Comment: The reason why I want to do that because the code is given to me by someone else, and it was done this way in the original code. I wanted to know if there is some way to differentiate between the two.

Answer (score -1):

I understand,

in this case, one thing you can do is this:

```
void SomeFn(int val) {



    int* val_value_holder = &val;

    for (int val = 0; val < 10; val++) {

        std::cout << *val_value_holder << " ";

    }

}
```

But again, this is technically not "using the same variable", but rather storing its post-

changed-in-loop value. And yes, as the other person here said, this is very poor coding

practise. Usually the variables in a loop are named i, j, counter, something like that.

Comment: I mean, ff you call not-forgetting to put a * just 2 lines after the intialisation of a pointer  in a 3-line-method "error-prone", sure hahah

Comment: Why should you, if you can simply choose a name which does *not* shadow your other variables? This "solution" solves a non-problem which only exists in the OPs head and has no connection to reality. Showing them how they can continue on their misguided path is counter-productive, especially if it increases complexity for no reason at all.

Comment: **Thank you pointing that out. I must be really out of touch to forget to tell the guy that this is poor coding practise at the end of the co-** oh, my bad.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

On c++ 11+ you can also do something like this:

```
void SomeFn(int val) {

    auto print_original_val = [=]() {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    };

    for (int val = 0; val < 10; val++) {
        print_original_val();
    }

}
```

, but I believe this is really far from what the person that gave you the code expects.

Comment: He probably expects from you just to create an additonal variable, and store the value of val there.